# how to iterating days

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops

I have a code for looping days.this to make leaves. I want column signin and signout on attendance will filling automatically start at startdate and end at enddate.

```
exp I input :
startdate: 2012-11-08 01:30:00
enddate: 2012-11-10 01:30:00
i want output like this: 

2012-11-08 01:30:00
2012-11-09 01:30:00
2012-11-010 01:30:00

 for i in 0..((@leafe.enddate - @leafe.startdate).to_i)
                 @attendance = Attendance.new

                 @attendance.signin = '2012-11-08 01:30:00' #value must chang automatically
                 @attendance.signout = '2012-11-08 10:30:00'#value must chang automatically
                 @attendance.user_id = @leafe.user_id
                 @attendance.save
            end
```

thanks before

Comment: I'm not sure I understand at all. What are the values for sign in and sign out dependent on?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to make looping days ruby on rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13283471/how-to-make-looping-days-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If startdate is of type Date, why not just do,

```
@attendance.signin = @leafe.startdate+i
@attendance.signout = @leafe.startdate+i
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you using for loop? It looks like javacode.
Use instead block with range like:

```
(Time.now.beginning_of_day.to_i..Time.now.to_i).step(3600) do |n|#step one hour for example
  @attendance = Attendance.new
  .......
  @attendance.signin  = @leafe.startdate
  @attendance.signout = @leafe.startdate + n # u can change time interval to any what you want

end
```