# how to make looping days ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to iterating days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13283239/how-to-iterating-days)

I have a code for looping days.this to make leaves. I want column signin and signout on attendance will filling automatically start at startdate and end at enddate.

```
**exp I input :**
startdate: 2012-11-08 01:30:00
enddate: 2012-11-10 01:30:00
**i want output like this:** 

2012-11-08 01:30:00
2012-11-09 01:30:00
2012-11-010 01:30:00

 for i in 0..((@leafe.enddate - @leafe.startdate).to_i)
                 @attendance = Attendance.new

                 @attendance.signin = '2012-11-08 01:30:00' #value must change automatically
                 @attendance.signout = '2012-11-08 10:30:00'#value must change automatically
                 @attendance.user_id = @leafe.user_id
                 @attendance.save
            end
```

for your answer i say thanks

Comment: Don't create new posts for the exact same question. Edit your old one.

Answer (score 1):

I really have problems understanding your problem description. I will just guess that you want to iterate over a range of dates.

```
start_date = Date.new(2012, 11, 8)
end_date   = Date.new(2012, 11, 23)

(start_date .. end_date).each do |date|
  …
  # Do something with date here
  …
end
```

Notice that I'm using the `Date` class here. You may need to load it first by using `require 'date'`. You should try to use specific classes that represent the things you are working with. Using an `Integer` or a `String` for dates is avoiding a lot of powerful `Date` specific functionality in a fully object-oriented language like Ruby.

As you don't only have a date as input but a full ISO-8601 time specification you probably want to use something like this to extract only the Date object:

```
Time.parse('2012-11-20 12:30:45').to_date
```

Here you may need to load it by using `require 'time'`.